# How to solve equation with matrix A*(X+B)=C (Not Squared)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In python it is possible to solve `A*x=B`. But is it possible to solve
`A*(B+x)=C` where x is the unknown vector and x1=0 so that we have 2 equations and 2 unknown values and becomes squared?

```
A= np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
B= np.array([10,20,-10])
C= np.array([0,0])

¿XX= np.array([0,1,1]) >> so that we only solve x2 and x3?

Solution: x = array([0, -40, 20])
```

I know I could do something like A*x=B,but I want to do it more straight forward:

```
A=np.array([[2,3],[2,1]])
B=np.array([-10,-30])
x=np.linalg.solve(A,B)

array([-20.,  10.])
```

In sum, I want an X vector that is (0, x2, x3), so that it becomes an equation that can be solved, but still don't know how to do it with the np.linalg.solve(). Then the system would be like this:

```
(10+x1) +( 40+2x2) - (30+3x3) = 0
(30+3x1) + (40+2x2) - (10+x3) = 0

10 + ( 40+2x2) - (30+3x3) = 0
30 + (40+2x2) - (10+x3) = 0
```

And only solve x2 and x3

Comment: You don't have a square matrix for the operation to succeed. Please check the example you have given. However you can rearrange the equation as has already been explained by Robin Nicole

Comment: Hi Amit, many thanks for your response. I undestandwhat you mean, that's why I want an X vector that is (0, x2, x3), so that it becomes an equation that can be solved, but still don't know how to do it with the np.linalg.solve(). Then the system would be like this:
`
(10+x1)   +( 40+2x2) - (30+3x3) = 0
(30+3x1) + (40+2x2) - (10+x3)   = 0

10 + ( 40+2x2) - (30+3x3) = 0
30 + (40+2x2) - (10+x3)   = 0
`
And only solve x2 and x3

Comment: @Rose _A_ is a 2×3 matrix, _x_ and _B_ are 3×1 vectors, the product _A·(x+B)_ is hence a 2×1 vector, ¡while your _C_ is described as a 3×1 vector!  There is a fundamental mistake in your question ¿may I assume that _C_ is a 2×1 vector? or is it a sort of eigenvalue problem in disguise?  Please [edit] your question, trying to be consistent and more helpful to your readers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can start by rewriting, A(x + b) = c as Ax + Ab = c, Ax = c - Ab. Furthermore we have an equation which states x0 = 0. We can capture this by stating a new problem with A' = [A; [1, 0, 0] and b' = [c - Ab; x0]. We can then solve the new problem as before.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [3, 2, 1]])
b = np.array([10, 20, -10])
c = np.array([0, 0])  # note this is different from the one you posted

x0 = 0   # first element of x

Aprime = np.vstack([A, [1, 0, 0]])
bprime = np.concatenate([c - A @ b, [x0]])

x = np.linalg.solve(Aprime, bprime)
```

This yields the answer you got ([0, -40, 20])

Comment: Many thanks! that's what I was looking for, really appreciate it

Comment: May I suggest that you write `b' = [c - Ab; x0]`? otherwise your solution works only for `x0 ≡ 0`

Comment: @gboffi Good call - I've reworded the explanation as well.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? 

Write a Python Program using SciPy that solves the
equation X = A * B * C, given X, B and C as input. In the
equation, X is a scalar, A is the unknown 1x2 vector, B
is a 2x2 matrix, and C is a 2x1 vector. The two
elements of A have the relationship A[1] = 1- A[0]

Find the value of vector A.
Example
X= 0.35
B= [[3, -1], [-2, 3]]
C= [0.2, 0.8]

After solving the equation X = A * B * C, the value of the vector A =[[0.75, 0.25 ]].

Comment: @bilalahmed381 Please ask a new top-level question on the site. We can't help you in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a programming question, is more about algebra, but however...

As I said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336763/how-to-solve-equation-with-matrix-axb-c-not-squared#comment101163228_57336763) the problem as stated is not consistent, and I have to **assume** (in part following your edit) that *C* is a 2×1 vector.  This type of problem calls for a *partitioning* of the vector quantities (oh, if Stack Overflow supported Mathjax!).

Lets a₀ be the first column of A, and A´ the matrix formed by the remaining two columns; using the notation x´ for the unknown part of the vector  we can write

```
 a₀ x₀ + A´ x´ = C - A B
```

where `a₀ x₀`, a vector multiplied by a scalar, is 2×1, `A´ x´` a 2×2 matrix by a 2×1 vector is a x1 vector and the right member is correct —as far as `C` is 2×1, that is— let's rewrite

```
A´ x´ = C - A B - a₀ x₀
```

Now we want to implement this in Python, using Numpy

```
# partition the coefficients
a0, A_ = A[0,:], A[1:,:]
# compute the right member
rm = C - A@B - a0*x0
# solve for the remaining unknowns
x_ = np.linalg.solve(A_, rm)
# form a vector with the whole solution
x = np.hstack((x0, x_))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your equation as `Ax = C - AB` and solve it with `np.linalg(A, C - A * B)` (add numpy dot product where needed)

Comment: I wonder how you were upvoted (people don't read the questions/don't know linear algebra) because ① following to the letter the question and the code provided C is 3×1 and AB is 2×1 and ②if that were not enough, np.linalg is a module and not a callable! Possibly the worse **upvoted** answer of the weekend

Comment: It seems like you had a bad day at work or something. As you said the problem was wrongly stated and I gave my fast answer to it. Now you are right that your answer is more complete and accurate than mine and I will upvote it but I would appreciate if you could be less aggressive in your next interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Edit begin

Your original equations were

10 + ( 40+2*x2) - (30+3*x3) = 0

30 + (40+2*x2) - (10+x3) = 0

But I read them as

10 + ( 40*2*x2) - (30*3*x3) = 0

30 + (40*2*x2) - (10*x3) = 0

and that's why my answer was as below.

Edit finished;

The above equation that you posted, can be rearranged into the following.

( 40*2*x2) - (30*3*x3) = -10

(40*2*x2) - (10*x3) = -30.

A and B are easily identifiable as:

A = np.array([[40*2,-30*3],[40*2,-10*1]]

B = np.array([[-10],[-30]])

Once you have identified above, rest is just a few lines.

```py
from numpy.linalg import solve
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[40*2,-30*3],[40*2,-10*1]]
B = np.array([[-10],[-30]])
X = solve (A,B)
print(X)
```

The output is

```py
[[-0.40625]
 [-0.25]]
```

I manually solved and the answer is correct. I am not sure if this was your requirement.